# what to include -- net/if.h or linux/if.h

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming, posix

I would like to use in my program symbols `IFNAMSIZ` or `IFF_*` e.g. `IFF_RUNNING or such. On my system (Ubuntu) these symbols are defined in two header files in /usr/include:`net/if.h`and`linux/if.h`

So which one I should include in my code to make it portable across other Linux distros?

Comment: You should almost never directly include any header files from `linux`. That's include this case. That will also make your source portable to non-Linux systems.

Comment: You mean, I should always include files from `/net/*` or such?

Comment: Yes. If needed, those header file will in turn include the implementation-specific header files which might include the `linux` header files.

Comment: `man -k if.h` returns a hit `net_if.h (0p)`. Then, `man net_if.h` provides a manpage from the POSIX programmer manual for *`net/if.h — sockets local interfaces`*. It goes on to say, *`IF_NAMESIZE` Interface name length"*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thanks for response. What to do with `ethtool`, it is defined only in `linux/ethtool.h`

Comment: What are your program *doing*? What problem is it supposed to solve? Why do you need symbols, macros or structures from internal Linux header files?

Comment: The program issues `ioctl()` calls to retrieve ethtool interface parameters from the kernel.

Comment: If you're communicating directly with the kernel then you might need to include the `linux` header files, and that's okay. It's also portable between Linux systems (as long as the Os is using a version of Linux supporting the interface).